# Runtime determination of JArray content types

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have to determine at runtime the type of the JSON's `JArray` object to use in a corresponding method:

Part of my JSON looks like:

```
{
  "$type": "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib],[System.Object, mscorlib]], mscorlib",
  "listdouble": {
    "$type": "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.Double, mscorlib]], mscorlib",
    "$values": [
      1,
      3
    ]
  },
  "listbool": {
    "$type": "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.Boolean, mscorlib]], mscorlib",
    "$values": [
      true,
      false
    ]
  },
  "liststring": {
    "$type": "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.String, mscorlib]], mscorlib",
    "$values": [
      null,
      " ",
      "New String"
    ]
  }
}
```

This is a part of Json serialized from `Dictionay<string, object>`. At runtime, it is deserialized to a dictionary with keys mapping to `JArrays`. I can use `ToObject` method upon `JArray` once I know the type of data contained in it, but how to determine what type is it made up of? Like whether a dictionary key maps to `List<double>` or `List<bool>` ?

Comment: why did you unmark my answer?

Comment: Must have been a wrong click mate. Your answer helped me get that right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what I would do is using dynamic object for deserialization of the JSON like

```
dynamic d = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString);
```

and then access the array by

```
JArray arrayOfDoubles = d.listdouble.values;
```

and check the containing types

```
List<JTokenType> listOfTypes = arrayOfDoubles.GroupBy(item => item.Type).Select(item => item.Key).ToList();
```

In this case the output of listOfTypes is

```
[0] Integer
```

but you can of course get an array of doubles out of it.

```
List<double> listOfDoubles = arrayOfDoubles.ToObject<List<double>>();
```

the result will be just fine:

```
[0] 1.0
[1] 3.0
```

same with the list of your bools:

```
JArray arrayOfBools = d.listbool.values;
listOfTypes = arrayOfBools.GroupBy(item => item.Type).Select(item => item.Key).ToList();
```

output of listOfTypes

```
[0] Boolean
```

Deserialization:

```
List<bool> listOfBools = a.ToObject<List<bool>>();
```

output:

```
[0] true
[1] true
```

the same will work for strings.

You could also deserialize your array from the type you provide, by

```
var type = d.listdouble.type; // "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.Double, mscorlib]], mscorlib"

var myType = Type.GetType(type.ToString()); // get the type out of it
var myGenericList = arrayOfDoubles.ToObject(myType);
```

`myGenericList` will be of type `{System.Collections.Generic.List<double>}` with the values [1.0, 3.0]. Works just fine.

So you could check your json type `d.listdouble.type` against the elements in your json array to ensure that it will be deserialized.

Hope this helps!